# How can I group the values in the object and push them in an array in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

Basically, I am given a data set just like the one I provided below and all follow the same pattern and have the same amount of keys and values, however; I am looking to group them in a way where the "make" stays the same, and if the array has more objects with the same "make" the "model" values are pushed into an array as shown in the example 2.

I have tried attempts using a Loop, but couldn't figure out how to produce 2 different arrays for a single make.

```
const cars = [
    {
        'make': 'audi',
        'model': 'r8',
        'year': '2012'
    }, {
        'make': 'audi',
        'model': 'rs5',
        'year': '2013'
    }
];
```

And here is the end result that I am looking for:

```
const carByMake = [
    {
        'make': 'audi',
        'models': ['r8', 'rs5']
        'years': ['2012, 2013']
    },
];
```

Comment: Can you share your attempts at this pls? We can't do the work for you, but we can certainly help guide on any issues you've come across and cannot resolve :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way more fundamental way to do what your asking.

This is a very basic problem, and should be solved using a basic solution. There isn't a need to filter the results, as a simple loop with an if statement can produce the results that your asking for. Fundamentally, the solution for this problem is technically a sort-algorithm, just a very simple one.

You could use a **"for of"** loop, but I feel like this is a prime example where a forEach loop shows how powerful it is. ForEach is abstracted a level above your low-level `while` & `for` loops. That extra layer of abstraction allows a function to be passed into the forEach loop. Each time (hence the name "each") the `forEach` loop iterates, the forEach's callback is executed, until the array that the forEach loop was called on has been fully iterated through (there are exceptions, but I don't want to get off track).

You can use the forEach loop to solve your problem. That solution is demonstrated below. I documented the code w/ ***JSDoc*** so you can copy & paste it into your editor, and have the parameters & types shown in your tool-tip/hover-widget.

```
const cars = [
    { make: 'audi', model: 'r8', year: 2012 },
    { make: 'audi', model: 'rs5', year: 2013 },
];

/**
 * @param {string} make - The make that you want to return the models & 
           years for
 * @param {{make: string, model: string, year: number}[]} cars - An 
           array of car objects that include the model make & year
 * @return {{make: string, models: string[], years: string[]}}
 * */
function sortByMake(make, cars) {
    const models = [];
    const years = [];

    cars.forEach((car) => {
        if (car.make.toLowerCase() === make.toLowerCase()) {
            models.push(car.model);
            years.push(car.year);
        }
    });

    return { make: make, models: models, years: years };
}

console.log(sortByMake('Audi', cars));

// OUTPUT:
// $ node ./index.js
// {make: 'Audi', models: ['r8', 'rs5'], years: [2012, 2013]}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
const cars = [
  {
    make: "audi",
    model: "r8",
    year: "2012",
  },
  {
    make: "audi",
    model: "rs5",
    year: "2013",
  },
  {
    make: "audi",
    model: "rs6",
    year: "2013",
  },
  {
    make: "bmw",
    model: "x5",
    year: "2013",
  },
  {
    make: "bmw",
    model: "x6",
    year: "2013",
  },
];

let tempArr = [];
let unique = cars.map((data) => {
  let filterDataArr = tempArr.filter(
    (filterData) => filterData.make == data.make
  );
  if (filterDataArr && filterDataArr.length > 0) {
    filterDataArr[0].models = [...filterDataArr[0].models, data.model];
    filterDataArr[0].years = [...filterDataArr[0].years, data.year];
  } else {
    let dataArr = {
      make: data.make,
      models: [data.model],
      years: [data.year],
    };

    tempArr.push(dataArr);
  }
});
console.log("tempArr=>", tempArr);
```